# Default Azure Function Times Out During Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I made like default azure function you get when you want a python function

```
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

and when i try to deploy it through vscode i'm getting the following:

```
11:42:59 AM func-patientprecheck-dev-05: Creating zip package...
11:42:59 AM func-patientprecheck-dev-05: Zip package size: 2.75 kB
11:44:10 AM: Error: request to https://func-patientprecheck-dev-05.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true&author=VS%20Code failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 20.40.24.37:443
```

I literally made no changes to it, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Tried to deploy the default Azure Python Function App from VS Code to Azure, deployed successfully:**

**Default HTTP Trigger Function Code:**

```py
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
name = req.params.get('name')
if  not  name:
try:
req_body = req.get_json()
except  ValueError:
pass
else:
name = req_body.get('name')  
if  name:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
else:
return  func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
status_code=200
)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Note:**

- There is something fault on Network level for causing this error.
- Please check your Network connection and firewall settings (Allow the ports required to run Azure Functions in VS Code if you're connected via proxy) which may blocking your connection when deploying to Azure.
- You may get this error when you're running the code on server using `HTTPS` port `443` with an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was because I was deploying to US West 3 which is apparently too new and can't handle python azure functions I guess, idk